# How to print out all handle attributes of DBI in Perl

Tags: perl, dbi

To make debugging a bit easier, I want to print out all the keys and values of all handle attributes in DBI.

I tried:

```
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $db = DBI->connect(etc);
print Dumper($db);
```

But I only see "bless {}, 'DBI::db'"
Is there a method in DBI itself or a variable I can print with Dumper(), that will print info on the internals of DBI?

Comment: Don't do that. Take a look at https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#DBI_TRACE to get a better idea of what's going on under the hood.

Comment: You likely have a chain of objects and object references within your `$db`. You'll need to disentangle it, and life is just too short for that sort of pain. (@BenGrimm - if you post that as an answer, I'll upvote :))

Comment: Hah @Sobrique, I just wanted to point out that there are better ways of debugging DBI. Schwern provided the only real answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your posts. In this case I just needed to know a quick way to inspect internal variables so Schwern's answer will suffice

Answer (score 10):

[The DBI docs mention in passing](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#swap_inner_handle)...

> A DBI handle is a reference to a tied hash. A tied hash has an inner hash that actually holds the contents.

You can get at this internal attribute hash with [`tied`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html).

```
print Dumper tied %$dbh;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about the 'tied' keyword